# android application delete only one sms in the inbox

Tags: android

hi friends 
I am create delete sms
It will delete sms successfully but i want to delete only one sms.
It can possible if possible than how can do it.
If its code available please send me.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this code.

```
try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
                        "date", "body" }, "read=0", null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                String date = c.getString(3);
                if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                    // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?",
                            new String[] { <your date>});
                    Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success.........");
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log>>>", e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For same thing i am looking for.

I am using this code with count ,Check if it works :

```
public void deleteOneSMS(int threadIdNo) {

    try {

    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id" }, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.move(threadIdNo)) {

        do {

            long threadId = c.getLong(1);

            count++;

            //System.out.println("threadId:: "+threadId);

            if (count == threadIdNo){

            getContentResolver().delete(
                    Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + threadId),
                    null, null);

                }

            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }
    }catch (Exception e) {

    // TODO: handle exception

    System.out.println("Exception:: "+e);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete only one sms at a time and not all conversation, then this example will help you, here i am getting the lates(top most) sms from inbox and delete them, remember that each sms has its thread and id value which differentiate it from other sms.

```
try
        {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");         
        Cursor c =v.getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null); 
        String body = null;
        String number = null;           
        if(c.moveToFirst()) 
        {}
        }
        catch(CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException ee)
            {
             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Error :"+ ee.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```